# 【JUCEでDAW自作】とりあえずビルドを成功させたいだけなんです

Tags: c++, visual-studio

#### 解決したいこと

とりあえずでいいからプロジェクトのビルドを成功させたい。ただそれだけ...

#### 前書き

・VS2022
・JUCE Framework
・DAWを自作しようとしている
どうも、No.0です。
さて、私の所属している学校には自由研究の長い版みたいなのがあります。
研究テーマを色々考えた結果、なんやかんやあってDAWを自作することにしてしまいました。(大馬鹿者)
取り敢えず、テンプレートはGUI、なんか追加出来るモジュールは全部追加してみて、VS2022を選択、slnを開いて何もコードをいじらずビルドしてみました。
すると画像のようなエラーが出て、ビルドが成功しません。[image: エラー画像]

#### 該当するソースコード

```
#if ! (JucePlugin_Build_VST || JucePlugin_Build_VST3 \
        || JucePlugin_Build_AU  || JucePlugin_Build_AUv3 \
        || JucePlugin_Build_AAX || JucePlugin_Build_Standalone \
        || JucePlugin_Build_LV2 || JucePlugin_Build_Unity)
 #error "You need to enable at least one plugin format!"
#endif

#ifdef JUCE_CHECKSETTINGMACROS_H
 #error "This header should never be included twice! Otherwise something is wrong."
#endif
#define JUCE_CHECKSETTINGMACROS_H

#ifndef JucePlugin_IsSynth
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_IsSynth value!"
#endif

#ifndef JucePlugin_ManufacturerCode
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_ManufacturerCode value!"
#endif

#ifndef JucePlugin_PluginCode
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_PluginCode value!"
#endif

#ifndef JucePlugin_ProducesMidiOutput
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_ProducesMidiOutput value!"
#endif

#ifndef JucePlugin_WantsMidiInput
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_WantsMidiInput value!"
#endif

#ifdef JucePlugin_Latency
 #error "JucePlugin_Latency is now deprecated - instead, call the AudioProcessor::setLatencySamples() method if your plugin has a non-zero delay"
#endif

#ifndef JucePlugin_EditorRequiresKeyboardFocus
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_EditorRequiresKeyboardFocus value!"
#endif

//==============================================================================
#if JucePlugin_Build_AAX && ! defined (JucePlugin_AAXIdentifier)
 #error "You need to define the JucePlugin_AAXIdentifier value!"
#endif
```

#### 自分で試したこと

色々と調べた結果、以下の記事を見つけました。
https://forum.juce.com/t/where-is-juceplugin-issynth-set-how-do-i-say-my-plugin-is-an-instrument-not-an-effect/27972
でも、Projucer のバージョンが変わったためか、この方法では問題は解決できませんでした。
同じ場所の設定を確認してもそのような項目はありません。
ソリューションエクスプローラーからAppConfig.hが見つからず、チュートリアルを読んでもわかりませんでした。
どうすりゃプラグイン読み込みとかを設定して解決出来るんでしょうか?
ご迷惑をおかけして申し訳ありません…

#### それと...

JUCEフォーラムに投稿した海外ニキ向けQ&A：
(Q&A posted on the JUCE forum for foreigners:)
https://forum.juce.com/t/how-to-resolve-juce-checksettingdefinemacro-h-errors/57132

そのうち共同開発者を募るつもりで自分のDiscordサーバーを準備中なんですけど、なんかこれでいいのか不安で中々リンクを貼る勇気が持てない...はぁ...

#### (2023/07/23 9:40追記)今回の質問でマルチポストを行っていたことの通達とそのお詫び

私はこの質問と同様の内容を他の複数のプログラミング系質問掲示板サイトでも投稿しています。
別に緊急を要する内容ではありませんでしたが、界隈の狭さを心配して出来るだけ有識者の目に触れることを期待しようとした結果今回のような違反をしてしまいました。
同様の投稿をした他サイト：
・teratail(https://teratail.com/questions/devypg60bd4tw9)
・Qiita(https://qiita.com/No-0/questions/774118b5b245edc08fb1)
この度は、無意識にヘルプの内容に違反する行為を行ってしまい、誠に申し訳ございません。
僕自身、今回初めて「マルチポスト」なる概念、マナー違反であることなどを(以前に見たかもしれないが)本格的に認知しました。
様々な文献でマルチポストへの批判等の文書が記載されていましたが、納得できる内容だったので尚更何も言えません。(めっちゃ言っとるやないか申し訳)
今後は出来る限りマルチポストと見られないような内容の投稿に努め、検索の有効性や情報蓄積の意義について意識しながら質問を投稿していこうと思います。
改めて、この度はご迷惑をおかけしてしまい、誠に申し訳ございませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

https://twitter.com/migizo/status/1682770862276247552
いけました！ご迷惑をおかけしてすみませんでした！
マルチポストは出来るだけ控えるようにしたいと思います...

#### 具体的な解決方法

大体画像のような感じで、
Projucerのプロジェクト設定画面から「modules」を選択
→「juce_audio_plugin_client」というmoduleをプロジェクトからリムーブ(画像はリムーブ済み　もう該当するmoduleはありません)
→Visual Studioを開き直します
→いつも通りShift+Ctrl+Bでビルドすると、
→ビルドに成功しました！
ぶっちゃけ外しちゃって支障ないのかはわかりませんが、ビルドするための解決方法は以上です。
[image: module画面の画像]

今回はご迷惑をおかけしてしまいすみませんでした。